# Can I get the arduino to run ESP8266 code?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, esp8266

So I got [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VKATCRQ) water flow sensor that measures the flow of water. I also got an ESP8266 module to help me make HTTP requests.

So as far as I know, one must set the board type to Generic ESP8266 and upload a sketch that the ESP8266 runs.

However, how can I write code in such a way that when the water flow goes over say 30 Litres, it makes a GET request to the Api that alerts the user? I am not able to use both the modules in one sketch. Any possible methods?

Comment: Can you add a link to the water flow sensor? What coms method does it use or is it have an analog output? Can you show us what you have tried so far? We aren't a code writing service.

Comment: @sa_leinad I added a link to the sensor. Majenko's answer was the one I was looking for. I've got what to do now.

Comment: why do you even need the uno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what you are working with.

There are two ways of working with an ESP8266:

1. Directly program the ESP8266. This involves installing the ESP8266 boards package and uploading the code to the ESP8266. No Arduino is required (unless you want to use one as a USB to UART adaptor for the programming).
2. Use the ESP8266 as a serial peripheral to an Arduino. You program the Arduino, not the ESP8266, and no special software is needed (unless you want to use an ESP8266 library for Arduino). You send the ESP8266 `AT` commands to get it to do internet related operations. *You are still working with an Arduino, so that is the board that should be selected.*

It sounds like you are wanting to do (2) but are mistakenly trying to so (1).

Option 2 does rely on the ESP8266 having the AI Thinker AT firmware installed on the ESP8266, which most come preinstalled with. If you have uploaded code to your ESP8266 using the ESP8266 boards package that firmware will have been replaced with your code and you will need to put the original firmware back on. There's many tutorials on the web showing you how.

If you do want to program the ESP8266 directly then it's the ESP8266 that you need to program, not an Arduino. Everything will be done by the ESP8266 - the GET request, the water flow sampling, the decision making, etc. The Arduino will be relegated to your bits box where it will gather dust.